# Count with muliple where conditions in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have the query below;

```
Select count(*) as poor
from records where deviceId='00019' and type='Poor' and timestamp between #14-Sep-2012 01:01:01# and #24-Sep-2012 01:01:01#
```

table is like;
id. deviceId, type, timestamp

data is like;

data is like;

```
1, '00019', 'Poor', '19-Sep-2012 01:01:01'
2, '00019', 'Poor', '19-Sep-2012 01:01:01'
3, '00019', 'Poor', '19-Sep-2012 01:01:01'
4, '00019', 'Poor', '19-Sep-2012 01:01:01'
```

i am trying to count the devices with a specific specific type.

Please help.. access always returns wrong data. it is returning 1 while 00019 has 4 entries for poor

Comment: Id have expected the query to work - please display some data so we can see what you're running it on

Comment: Try your query as it is just leaving timestamp condition `Select count(*) as poor
from records where deviceId='00019' and type='Poor'` I hope it will work because most probably there only inconsistency between your string and access time stamp, your remaining query is alright. If it is the case which most likely be, update your question just inquiring about time-stamp format or search it and you will be guided easily.

Comment: @Sami: timestamp format is correct.
HansUp: no it is by mistake, let me correct it.

Comment: OK. Please don't say it is correct. I am not claimed, i just suspected. But just say please that you have tried this without time stamp as i told in comment above and its still wrong? But say after checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type and timestamp are both reserved words, so enclose them in square brackets in your query like this: `[type]` and `[timestamp]`.  I doubt those reserved words are the cause of your problem, but it's hard to predict exactly when reserved words will cause query problems, so just rule out this possibility by using the square brackets.

Beyond that, stored text values sometimes contained extra non-visible characters.  Check the lengths of the stored text values to see whether any are longer than expected.

```
SELECT
    Len(deviceId) AS LenOfDeviceId,
    Len([type]) AS LenOfType,
    Len([timestamp]) AS LenOfTimestamp
FROM records;
```

In comments you mentioned spaces (ASCII value 32) in your stored values.  I had been thinking we were dealing with other non-printable/invisible characters.  If you have one or more actual space characters at the beginning and/or end of a stored `deviceId` value, the `Trim()` function will discard them.  So this query will give you different length numbers in the two columns:

```
SELECT
    Len(deviceId) AS LenOfDeviceId,
    Len(Trim(deviceId)) AS LenOfDeviceId_NoSpaces
FROM records;
```

If the stored values can *also* include spaces within the string (not just at the beginning and/or end), `Trim()` will not remove those.  In that case, you could use the `Replace()` function to discard all the spaces.  Note however a query which uses `Replace()` must be run from inside an Access application session --- you can't use it from Java code.

```
SELECT
    Len(deviceId) AS LenOfDeviceId,
    Len(Replace(deviceId, ' ', '')) AS LenOfDeviceId_NoSpaces
FROM records;
```

If that query returns the same length numbers in both columns, then we are not dealing with actual space characters (ASCII value 32) ... but some other type of character(s) which look "space-like".

Comment: regarding the spaces, you are right.. there are some with more characters than normal. how to trim the white spaces.

Comment: More info please.  Which field or fields include invisible characters?  Do some stored text values include more than one invisible character?

Comment: Do you intend to run your query only from within an Access application session?  Or must the query also be suitable for use from external clients ... classic ASP, Dot.Net, PHP, Java, etc.?

Comment: If you can clean the stored values, the query task will be *much* easier.  Would that be a reasonable option in your situation?

Comment: stored text values contain white spaces mostly in deviceId, and in type.
i am running the query from java application
how to clean the stored values easily, it will be hard to update 100s of records manually

Comment: i tried ;
UPDATE records SET type=TRIM(type)
 and 
UPDATE records SET deviceId=TRIM(deviceId)

but still only 1 record is returning where it should be 4 for the above query, same problem and your query is still showing the same results, it means the query executed successfully but the white spaces are still there

Comment: it is confirmed that the problem is of white spaces, i tested it in the test table with 4 records and now its returning 4 records, i will further like to share that the table records are generated from a dotnet application while i am reading it from java application. my application is generating reports while the dotnet is for enteries. so i will like to have a solution that i can do from java or dotnet. on the runtime of application it will not be possible to run a query in access session.

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation; that was a critically important point.  IMO the ideal solution would be to eliminate the unwanted spaces at the source ... when the rows are saved by your Dot.Net app.  However, I suspect that won't be an option.  If it's not an option, I think you'll have to use db engine-supported functions such as `Instr()` and `Mid()` to reconstruct the stored values without spaces.  It could be ugly.  I suggest you submit a new question.  We've identified the problem; the new question will be about how to solve it.

Comment: Include sample values which cover the range of conditions you encounter.  And make it clear that you want to do this with an Access query from Java client code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count devices with specific type irrespective of deviceids then use this:

```
Select count(*) as excellent
from records where type='Poor'
```

If you want to count devices with specific deviceid irrespective of types then use this:

```
Select count(*) as excellent
from records where deviceId='00019'
```

Comment: i want it with both condition, will also like a third condition of timestamp; like; between '20-09-2012' and '24-09-2012'

Comment: in that case what you were trying above is correct.And I guess its returning 1 bcos 00019 has 1 value with type='poor' and rest 3 will be of different types

Comment: easy way to check, `Select Type, count(*) from records where deviceId='00019' GROUP BY Type`

Comment: i have updated the query and data.. i am not getting the correct result. am i doing something wrong? i am using ms access